# Using URI multi-argument constructor, how can I include `%2F` in the URI?

Tags: java, uri

When using `new URI(..., ..., path, ..., ...)`, I need to produce a URI that includes `%2F` (encoded forward slash). However, I can't find a way to do that.

This is for using the GitLab API, which requires this for namespaced project names:

> If using namespaced projects call make sure that the NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME is URL-encoded, eg. `/api/v3/projects/diaspora%2Fdiaspora` (where `/` is represented by `%2F`).

If I set the `path` argument to `/foo/bar%2Fstool` it causes the URI to output `/foo/bar%%2Fstool` (it escapes the `%`, as the Javadocs indicate it would).

If I set it to `/foo/bar/stool` then I will, of course, just get `/foo/bar/stool` out at the end.

How can I get the `URI` multi-argument constructor to NOT escape the `%` character in the `path` parameter, or is there some other way I can get it to do this?

Note that I don't have a choice of calling a different constructor; I'm not the one that's actually calling it. I'm using third-party code that is constructing the `URI` object.

Thanks!